How exactly does the carbon cycle work to transport nutrients?
In general, I know that the carbon cycle recycles carbon and transports it to various locations. However, in my biology class (I'm a freshman in high school), they gave us a diagram depicting the carbon cycle and I was confused on a few of the steps. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to download the diagram in the necessary format, so I will do my best to explain what it looked like. Essentially, in one step, it showed an arrow leading from detritivores (which also included soil microbes) to wood and fossil fuels. Basically, it was showing that there was a direct connection between detritivores breaking down detritus and the formation of wood and fossil fuels. Can anyone explain this connection? I haven't been able to find a source about it. If anyone has any sources or articles I can read to gain a better understanding, please post them as well. Thank you!

Welcome User. Remember we have a one question per post policy. Can you [edit] down. Any further questions should be posted in their own threads

Thank you for letting me know, I will edit it.

Thanks for the edit. The question is basically what, exactly, happens to decomposed carbon-containing matter;  how is it related to cellular respiration? What is the end product of respiration? Please read about it in the link provided, and a link with a quote including an explanation of exactly what confuses you (a requirement on this site) will help us identify the best starting point for helping you. Thanks.

I was wondering how decomposers release carbon into wood or fossil fuels (how carbon goes from the decomposer stage to the wood/fossil fuels stage), as that was what the diagram implied. I may be incorrect, and again I apologize for being unable to upload the diagram.
